# How to set date format in DatePicker bokeh

Tags: python, datepicker, bokeh

I m building a page with some chart using Bokeh and Python. I m using DatePicker to show a field to select a Date.

This is the code:

```
date_pickerStart = DatePicker(title='', value=dateStart, width=100)
```

now this field is displayed in the page and the user can select the date using the calendar. After set the date I can display it in the follow format:
yyyy-mm-dd

I need to set another format or even better another language (italian language) and the format should be like this:
dd-mm-yyyy

Is possible to do this?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer that supports both date format and Italian language?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to change the date format. it's a new feature on `ver 3.1`, you can see the feature request on [github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8926).
upgrade the package to a newer version.

```bash
pip install bokeh>=3.1 --upgrade
```

simply use `date_format` attribute

```py
date_picker = DatePicker(title='Select date', value="2019-09-20", date_format="d-m-Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remember date_picker is built on top of jquery

In JQuery this is how you can change the dateFormat

```
.datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
```

I suggest using this code to change and verify format changes

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, DatePicker
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
output_notebook(INLINE)
date_picker = DatePicker(title='Select date', value = '2020-05-19',date_format="d-m-y")
show(date_picker)
```

I have this code running here - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u6oDi--9bkSXQ8E-ZZn46a98_uXueuAV?usp=sharing

Good and luck and enjoy coding!

Ref:

1. https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DatePicker.html
2. https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option
3. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-date-format-in-jquery-ui-datepicker/#